# Android - Set a different padding for each direction using a single statement

Tags: android, android-layout

In CSS, one can set a different padding for top, right, bottom and left using the following, 1 line statement:

```
padding: 5px,10px,15px,5px;
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do the same while implementing a layout in Android XML. Currently, to achieve the same result (using `dp` instead of `px`), I do it this way:

```
android:paddingTop="5dp";
android:paddingRight="10dp";
android:paddingBottom="15dp";
android:paddingLeft="5dp";
```

So, is there a way to do the above in a single statement? For example:

```
android:padding="5dp,10dp,15dp,5dp";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in Java (and if you want your values to be in dp):

```
float dp5 = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 5, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
view.setPadding(dp5, dp5*2, dp5*3, dp5);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes but you cannot do that in **XML** but you can do it in your **java code**

```
btn_submit.setPadding(5,10,7,8);
```

Comment: Fair enough but I wouldn't want to set everything else in xml and ressort to Java to set the padding this way. This is why I hoped there would be an XML solution.